# UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server with ChromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class tttt {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<>();
        //mePrefs.put("download.default_directory", new File(RobotPay.class.getClassLoader().getResource("alipaycaptchatmp/").getFile()).getAbsolutePath());
        chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
        chromePrefs.put("download.directory_upgrade", true);
        chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled",true);
        chromePrefs.put("profile.managed_default_content_settings.images", 2);//禁图片
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", args[0]);
        options.setBinary(args[1]);


        ChromeDriver dr = new ChromeDriver(options);


    }
}
```

<strike>error:</strike>

```
[qateadmin@UAT13352 ~]$ java -cp "/opt/tars/apps/100018485/releases/762245/WEB-INF/lib/*:./" tttt /opt/tars/apps/100018485/releases/762245/WEB-INF/classes/seleniumdriver/chromedriver /usr/bin/google-chrome
Starting ChromeDriver 2.45.615279 (12b89733300bd268cff3b78fc76cb8f3a7cc44e5) on port 4461
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'UAT13352', ip: '10.5.117.188', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:159)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:148)
        at tttt.main(tttt.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The process has not exited yet therefore no result is available ...
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecuteResultHandler.getException(DefaultExecuteResultHandler.java:76)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.checkForError(UnixProcess.java:171)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.checkForError(CommandLine.java:185)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:177)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:166)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
        ... 7 more
```

chrome version:

```
[qateadmin@UAT13352 ~]$ google-chrome -version
Google Chrome 71.0.3578.98
```

chrome executable mode is `777`

chromedriver version:`2.45`(Supports Chrome v70-72,mode is `777`)

OS:`centos_x64`

Also, i have tested it on my local Ubuntu16.04_x64 and CentOS7_x64 virtual machine with no exception.
I am stuck at this problem,any suggestion?

---

**updates**
after upgraded java to `Java SE 8u191`,the error messages now is:

```
[qateadmin@UAT13352 ~]$ java -cp "/opt/tars/apps/100018485/releases/762245/WEB-INF/lib/*:./" tttt /opt/tars/apps/100018485/releases/762245/WEB-INF/classes/seleniumdriver/chromedriver /usr/bin/google-chrome
Starting ChromeDriver 2.45.615279 (12b89733300bd268cff3b78fc76cb8f3a7cc44e5) on port 3602
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'UAT13352', ip: '10.5.117.188', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:159)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:148)
        at tttt.main(tttt.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The process has not exited yet therefore no result is available ...
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecuteResultHandler.getException(DefaultExecuteResultHandler.java:76)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.checkForError(UnixProcess.java:171)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.checkForError(CommandLine.java:185)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:177)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:166)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
        ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'UAT13352', ip: '10.5.117.188', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The process has not exited yet therefore no result is available ...
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *JDK version* is **1.7.0_51** which is pretty ancient.
- Your *Selenium Client* version is **2.53.1** of **2016-06-30 19:26:09** which is almost **3 years** older.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v7u51*, *Selenium Client v2.53.1*, *ChromeDriver v2.45* and *Google Chrome 71.0.3578.98*.

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u191**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.141.59**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.45**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v670-72*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.42 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: Uninstalled java7,installed java8,recompiled code,rebooted server.But still the same error pops out ,except now it says ```java.version: '1.8.0_121'```

Comment: @abracadabra Go up till JDK 8u191

Comment: I upgraded to ```Java SE 8u191``` ,but still the same error log except the java_version. @DebanjanB

Comment: @abracadabra Checkout my answer update and let me know the status